# Aggregating Several Data Sets in R

Tags: r

I have several data frame objects in R

```
dataset1
dataset2
dataset3
...
```

I am trying to row bind them using the rbind command using a loop but I am having a tough time looping the loop index into the string of characters that indexes the datasets.

```
x=dataset1
for (i in 2:n-1){
  assign(x,rbind(x,paste("dataset",i)))
}
```

or would the following work better:

```
x=rbind(x,paste("dataset",i))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you can read the datasets in as a list, they'll be much easier to work with and you won't have this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither will work: `paste` is simply creating a string, that you're either `rbind`ing or `assign`ing.

I think what you're looking for is `eval(parse(text=...))`.  So something like this would work:

```
datasets <- sapply(1:n, function(i) paste0("dataset", i))
expr <- paste0("rbind(", paste(datasets, collapse=", "), ")")
x <- eval(parse(text=expr))
```

**EDIT: Explaining why original code won't work**

When you use `paste` you're creating a string. For example lets say you have 20 datasets, and you run the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  paste("dataset", i)
}
"dataset 1"
"dataset 2"
"dataset 3"
...
"dataset 20"
```

So now what happens if you try to `rbind` that to some dataset? Lets try with a dummy dataset:

```
dataset1 <- head(mtcars)
dataset1
##                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

i <- 2
x <- rbind(dataset1, paste("dataset", i)
x
##                         mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        ## vs        am      gear      carb
## Mazda RX4                21         6       160       110       3.9      2.62     16.46         ## 0         1         4         4
## Mazda RX4 Wag            21         6       160       110       3.9     2.875     17.02         ## 0         1         4         4
## Datsun 710             22.8         4       108        93      3.85      2.32     18.61         ## 1         1         4         1
## Hornet 4 Drive         21.4         6       258       110      3.08     3.215     19.44         ## 1         0         3         1
## Hornet Sportabout      18.7         8       360       175      3.15      3.44     17.02         ## 0         0         3         2
## Valiant                18.1         6       225       105      2.76      3.46     20.22         ## 1         0         3         1
## 7                 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 ## dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2 dataset 2
```

You wanted to combine `dataset1` and `dataset2`, but all thats happened is you've added an extra row filled with `"dataset 2"` in each column! This is what would happen in your second code block if you tried to run:

```
x=rbind(x,paste("dataset",i))
```

So now what's wrong with your first code block:

```
x=dataset1
for (i in 2:n-1){
  assign(x,rbind(x,paste("dataset",i)))
}
```

First of all you will receive this error:

```
Error in assign(x, rbind(x, paste("dataset", i))) : 
  invalid first argument
```

`assign` actually takes a string, not a variable, and assigns some value to it:

```
assign("y", 5)
y
## [1] 5
```

That's why you see that error. So what would happen if you changed it to `"x"` instead?:

```
x=dataset1
for (i in 2:n-1){
  assign("x",rbind(x,paste("dataset",i)))
}
```

Well the second argument of the assign command, you've already seen what that does above. it will add a row containing "dataset i" to the existing `x`. `assign` will the assign it back into `x`. So the end result:

```
                         mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb
Mazda RX4                 21          6        160        110        3.9       2.62      16.46          0          1          4          4
Mazda RX4 Wag             21          6        160        110        3.9      2.875      17.02          0          1          4          4
Datsun 710              22.8          4        108         93       3.85       2.32      18.61          1          1          4          1
Hornet 4 Drive          21.4          6        258        110       3.08      3.215      19.44          1          0          3          1
Hornet Sportabout       18.7          8        360        175       3.15       3.44      17.02          0          0          3          2
Valiant                 18.1          6        225        105       2.76       3.46      20.22          1          0          3          1
7                  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2
8                  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1  dataset 1
9                  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2  dataset 2
10                 dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3  dataset 3
11                 dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4  dataset 4
12                 dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5  dataset 5
13                 dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6  dataset 6
14                 dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7  dataset 7
15                 dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8  dataset 8
16                 dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9  dataset 9
17                dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10 dataset 10
18                dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11 dataset 11
19                dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12 dataset 12
20                dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13 dataset 13
21                dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14 dataset 14
22                dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15 dataset 15
23                dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16 dataset 16
24                dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17 dataset 17
25                dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18 dataset 18
26                dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19 dataset 19
```

Comment: `library(fortunes);fortune('parse()')`

Comment: Thanks Scotty your awsome!! Though I am still confused as to why the code I wrote earlier doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer going through what would happen if you ran your code. Hopefully that makes things clearer!

Answer (score 2):

You're just trying to `rbind` several data frames? Try something like:

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- mtcars

df <- do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3))
```

And I think what you are missing is `get`. Try this:

```
paste0('df', 1:3)

tmp <- lapply(paste0('df',1:3), get)
```

Comment: You still need to `rbind` the list of datasets after you get `tmp` in your second code block.

Comment: That was obviously to demonstrate `get`. I had already answered the question with the first block

Comment: True, but it may not be obvious how to combine them. To answer the user's original question: `x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0('dataset', 1:n), get))`